# if null assign value 0, if statement code reuse

Tags: php

If my value is equal to null then I want to assign the value of 0 instead of having null. I've achieved that using my if statement however, its a lot of code production and I plan on adding more social networks is there a better way of achieving this.

```
$google = $request->input('google');
$facebook = $request->input('facebook');

if ($request->input('google') == null){
    $google = 0;
} else {
    $google = 1;
}

if ($request->input('facebook') == null){
    $facebook = 0;
} else {
    $facebook = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trenary operator

```
$google = ($request->input('google') == null) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent repeating the same code for each social networks you can do this.

```
$providers = array(
    'google',
    'facebook',
);

foreach ($providers as $provider) {
    if ($request->input($provider) == null) {
        $$provider = 0;
    } else {
        $$provider = 1;
    }
}
```

IMO the drawback is creating a dynamic variable name, to prevent this, you need to some modifications :

```
$providers = array(
    'google' => 0,
    'facebook' => 0,
);

foreach ($providers as $providerKey => $providerValue) {
    if ($request->input($providerKey) != null) {
        $providers[$providerKey] = 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps